# removing '#' from the url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have my site running but when I click on a tab that is linked to an anchor, it gives me `https://www.example.com/#contact` or `https://www.example.com/about`. How do I remove the '#'? I have the below scrolling query.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  //smoothscroll
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
      menu = target;
    var target = $(this.hash);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: (target.offset().top) - 79
    }, 500, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target;
      $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) like so:

```js
// www.domain.com/#something
window.history.pushState(null, null, '/your/path');
// www.domain.com/your/path
```

Comment: on the jquery script above where do i add it

Comment: assuming you want to scroll to a given place, then remove the # anchor probably in your scroll event handler function `onScroll`

Answer (score -1):

This is JS,not PHP. If in PHP, you can use `parse_url` function to parse the url at first.

```
$url = '//www.example.com/path#somearchor?googleguy=googley';
var_dump(parse_str($url));
```

It will output:

```
array(3) {
  ["host"]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(5) "/path"
  ["fragment"]=>
  string(28) "somearchor?googleguy=googley"
}
```

The the archor parts disappear.